# AutoSize RichTextBox results in large white space

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I have a class which inherits from `RichTextBox`.  I override resized

```
    protected override void OnContentsResized(ContentsResizedEventArgs e)
    {            
        this.Width = e.NewRectangle.Width;
        this.Height = e.NewRectangle.Height;
        this.Width += this.Margin.Horizontal + SystemInformation.HorizontalResizeBorderThickness;/*+ SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarThumbWidth Use if ScrollBars are visible */

        base.OnContentsResized(e);
    }
```

This works...kind-of.  This method creates a ton of white space in the bottom (roughly 2 * real content).  This method is called many times from `[External Code]`.  This is a a basic unit test where I stick this `RichTextBox` on a `Form` and set `Rtf`...that's about all.  So why does my resize method get called a ridiculous # of times (~30x)?

**Call Stack**

```
BHCS.ECC.dll!PhysDoc.Plugins.BayRichTextBox.OnContentsResized(System.Windows.Forms.ContentsResizedEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Forms.ContentsResizedEventArgs}) Line 74 + 0x42 bytes   C#
[External Code] 
BHCS.ECC.dll!PhysDoc.Plugins.BayRichTextBox.OnContentsResized(System.Windows.Forms.ContentsResizedEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Forms.ContentsResizedEventArgs}) Line 74 + 0x42 bytes   C#
[External Code] 
BHCS.ECC.dll!PhysDoc.Plugins.BayRichTextBox.OnContentsResized(System.Windows.Forms.ContentsResizedEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Forms.ContentsResizedEventArgs}) Line 74 + 0x42 bytes   C#
[External Code] 
BHCS.ECC.dll!PhysDoc.Plugins.BayRichTextBox.OnContentsResized(System.Windows.Forms.ContentsResizedEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Forms.ContentsResizedEventArgs}) Line 74 + 0x42 bytes   C#
[External Code] 
BHCS.ECC.UnitTests.dll!BHCS.ECC.UnitTests.LibUI_Tests.RTFTests.RtfTestClass.ProductionLabTest() Line 63 + 0x2c bytes    C#
[External Code]
```

When I show External Code a lot is going on.  The previous call on the stack in external code is

> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.WmReflectNotify(ref
>   System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message}) +
>   0x481 bytes

All the while `e.NewRectangle.Height` and `Width` values go up and down in a meaningless pattern.  The final height and width are not max values. I don't care so much about the event firing.  How can I fix this method to calculate size without adding white space to the end?

Note that a Get of `Text` property returns `some words \t \n`.  As you can see, there's not 300 newlines or anything to account for the white space.

Comment: Is it possible that changing Width and Heigth the ContentResized event is called again?

Comment: @Steve - I manually skipped these lines in the debugger and it still got called a bunch of times.  I also tried skipping the call to base, but no difference.